# WooCommerce Product Vendors: Send notification to vendor for new order received

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications, vendors

I am using **[WooCommerce Product Vendors](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-vendors/)** plugin for vendor management.

Currently, when a new order is received the notification is sent to customer and admin. Once admin change order status to **Processing** or **Completed** then the email is sent to Vendor.

But I need to send that notification email when an order is received.

Can this be achieved by creating a filter in `functions.php` or maybe by triggering product status change notification on order received?

Comment: By default, order status is Pending Payment and vendor will change order status to Processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: Added "New booking" email notification Id…

There is many ways to achieve that. **Here I have 2 of them:**

1). The first one, based on email ID "new Order". It is tested and works:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'new_order_email_to_vendor', 20, 4 );
function new_order_email_to_vendor( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    if( in_array( $email->id, ['new_order', 'new_booking'] ) ){ 
        $mailer['WC_Product_Vendors_Order_Email_To_Vendor']->trigger( $order );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

2). This is untested as it's based on order status change conditions. You can set in the if statement the "from" order statuses or some "to" order statuses or both…

Here I use the "from" 'pending' order status only, as all orders are always set in pending status during the payment process in Woocommerce:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'new_order_email_to_vendor', 10, 4 );
function new_order_email_to_vendor( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){

    if ( in_array( $new_status, array( 'processing','completed') ) { // <== Updated
        $emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();
        $emails['WC_Product_Vendors_Order_Email_To_Vendor']->trigger( $order );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Comment: Thank you so much for answer, actually the new order email is generated when the admin change the order status to **Processing** or **Completed**. The first email which is sent is about new booking and that is available on this path: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/templates/emails/admin-new-booking.php` so I want to trigger that email with this.

Comment: We are almost there, It trigger email but that email is little different from the email, which is normally sent to vendor. The email, which needs to trigger is available at: `woocommerce-product-vendors/templates/emails/order-email-to-vendor.php`

Comment: BTW, I can trigger the new email event where is new booking mail process starts. Like when the new order email is generated to admin and customer, I can trigger vendor email at that time. I am unable to locate the actual mail function (there are several so I'm not sure which one exactly call new order email). And I was able to locate email templates but don't understand; how they are called and where. Maybe this is not the proper way but it can solve the issue. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to access Skype because of some holidays and I need to reset the password as well :P. What's your opinion about modifying `$this->recipient = $this->get_option( 'recipient', get_option( 'admin_email' ) );` directly in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/includes/emails/class-wc-email-new-booking.php` and pass vendor email and I think it will work.

Comment: I've no problem in accepting the answer, (maybe) that's again the stackoverflow policies because that doesn't work for the issue. So, it could mislead the future users. And I'm not using it because above hook is called when order is placed whereas I need to call on new booking. So, I tried booking hook but it throws error. Maybe because it requires order creation data like order date etc which is generated once actual order is created. The method I'm trying to do is not proper way so some experts recommends; not to do in that way so I just posted that code as a reference to show that I tried

Comment: If you still think, I should accept then I accept it. BTW, one working solution will lead to both answers acceptation/up-votes.

Comment: Boss you seems unhappy. I really sorry for that and I truly respect you! And I don't use skype regularly so I was unable to login and it was long weekend so I didn't try to reset it. And just for clarification, `new_booking` and `new_order` are two different events. I need to trigger `new_booking` notification to vendor admin. The actual order is created when payment is processed or admin or vendor admin approves order.

Comment: There are 3 roles involve, administrator(site admin), vendor admin(manages vendors) and vendors(create products). When the booking is placed to vendor product and email is sent to admin and customer, whereas I want to send to vendor admin (who manages that vendor).

Comment: Thanks. I have answered to your new question, trying to find a good turn around as I really don't know anything about WC Vendor plugin. I hope that it will helps until you will find the right clean way… You should push it in WC Vendor support threads.

Comment: I am not sure if should ask it into a separate question! But my question is quite similar to this one.

What if I want to send a push notification when a new order is placed to the Android App that we created for Vendors. I think the process would be much close to what @LoicTheAztec has provided in point 2. 

I will be using AWS SNS service for the push notification service. All the solutions I have seen are notification via email but not getting any references for push notification for new orders to Vendor.

Comment: This solution worked for me but with the `new_order` (before you updated your code): https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47550189/revisions